# How to change color of unselected tab?

Tags: vimrc

Hello I am a pretty new user to vim, and am using nvim with ayu theme. The tabs dont look that great so I decided to edit the `ayu.vim`, and so far I changed the TabLineFill property to fit my preferences, however the color of the unselected tab is something I don't know how to change, so which property should I change for unselected tabs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The available highlight groups for tabpage line (see `:h tabpage`) are the following :

```
TabLine     tab pages line, not active tab page label
TabLineFill tab pages line, where there are no labels
TabLineSel  tab pages line, active tab page label
```

See `:h hl-Tabline`, `:h TabLineFill` and `:h TabLineSel` for documentation.

So, the **highlight group of the unselected tabpage line tab** would be `TabLine` whose colors can be configured as in the following (see `:h :highlight` for more info) :

```
hi TabLine    gui=NONE guibg=#3e4452 guifg=#abb2bf    cterm=NONE term=NONE ctermfg=black ctermbg=white
```

Here all parts with keyword `gui` will work for terminal emulators with true color support and if `:h termguicolors` has been enabled. See, `:h cterm-colors` and `:h gui-colors` for more details on them.